# Kids'(?) sci-fi book, clowns and robots

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, robots

I remember only one small part where one of the characters, disguised as a clown, notices a small robot spying on him and throws an object at the robot, destroying it. The robots were the antagonists in the story. I believe the book was illustrated.